# Python 2.7 attribute error on custom module

Tags: python, module, attributes, package

I'm running Debian Jessie with Python 2.7 installed. I tried to create this tiny module called linalg.py which only contains a few helper functions. I added the folder with the module into the PYTHONPATH hoping that it would allow me to simply import it from any python project.
The problem is that when I import it and call any of the functions, I get

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '<xyz>'
```

I have added an `__init__.py` into the directory with my module. The tree looks like this:

```
custom-packages/
  python2.7/
    linalg/
      linalg.py
      __init__.py
```

PYTHONPATH contains the python2.7 directory from above.
The file in question (linalg.py)

```
import sympy
import numpy as np

from numpy import dot


def vector(*lst):
  return np.array(lst)


def _projection(a, b):
  return sympy.Rational(dot(a, b), dot(b, b)) * b


def projection(a, *b):
  result = np.zeros(len(a))
  for vec in b:
    result += _projection(a, vec)
  return result


def perpendicular(a, *vecs):
  a_hat = projection(a, *vecs)
  return a - a_hat
```

if I run the following on the python shell I get the attribute error:

```
>>> import linalg
>>> linalg.vector(1,2,3,4)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'vector'
```

Using `from linalg import *` doesn't help.

Comment: That's not `linalg.vector`; that's `linalg.linalg.vector`.

Comment: You haven't clearly indicated which directory you added to the PYTHONPATH - the `linalg` directory, or the `python2.7` directory (or both? or something else?).

Comment: My PYTHONPATH is '/home/adam/custom-packages/python2.7'
Also doing linalg.linalg.vector gives me the attribute error again
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'linalg'

Comment: You didn't import `linalg.linalg`.

Comment: You should probably just get rid of the outer `linalg` package entirely, though. Pull `linalg.py` up a directory, delete the `linalg` directory and its `__init__.py`, and `linalg.py` will be the `linalg` module. Then you'll be able to access `vector` as `linalg.vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want your `linalg.py` to be the `linalg` module, but you've actually made it the `linalg` submodule of a `linalg` package. With how you have things set up now, you'd have to access `vector` as something like

```
import linalg.linalg

linalg.linalg.vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

but you probably shouldn't do that. Instead, you should pull `linalg.py` up a directory and delete the `linalg` folder, so your directory structure looks like

```
custom-packages/
  python2.7/
    linalg.py
```

and then

```
import linalg

linalg.vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

will work.